# Analysing a contract to figure out if SPAM coin or not

Tags: blockchain, erc-20

ok, looking at contract, trying to figure out if being spammed or not.

https://etherscan.io/bytecode-decompiler?a=0x732e9b5f59c9a442db18f7d57dd2bbfc804281cb